# Difficulty configuring an Amazon SES email SMTP in Mutt?

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ses, email-client, mutt

I have a verified AWS SES e-mail which I need to configure for use with Mutt.

I have tried several configurations based on the Mutt documentation for SMTP that haven't worked. Also, apparently the guide to setup SES with Mutt doesn't exist anywhere on the Internet, even though there are people saying that they have done it. Is there a configuration template I can use?